# Get the first element of pointer array in C?

Tags: c, readline

I've been searching for a while now on how to do this. The methods I have found have not yielded success so far.

[GNU Readline Info](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html)

Within that page, there is an example program called fileman.c, in particular this function:

```
/* Execute a command line. */
int
execute_line (line)
     char *line;
{
  register int i;
  COMMAND *command;
  char *word;

  /* Isolate the command word. */
  i = 0;
  while (line[i] && whitespace (line[i]))
    i++;
  word = line + i;

  while (line[i] && !whitespace (line[i]))
    i++;

  if (line[i])
    line[i++] = '\0';

  command = find_command (word);

  if (!command)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "%s: No such command for FileMan.\n", word);
      return (-1);
    }

  /* Get argument to command, if any. */
  while (whitespace (line[i]))
    i++;

  word = line + i;

  /* Call the function. */
  return ((*(command->func)) (word));
}
```

I am trying to understand how to access the char *word in such a way to be able to inspect it's elements? For example - if I wanted to check that the first element of the char *word is '#' and based on that do certain logic as opposed to when the word starts with anything else? I'm new to C and find that I have become accustomed to a lot of things in other languages; cough Python; that are inherently more difficult in C.

Thanks!

Comment: Your function declaration style is obsolete since about 1990. What are you using for reference? It should be `int execute_line (lchar* line)` (but this is not your issue)

Comment: How about `word[0] == '#'`?

Comment: What does this have to do with operating-system, gnu or readline? Seems to be an "I'm to lazy to read page 1 of the chapter on pointers" question...

Comment: John3136 if you don't have anything useful to add why add anything at all? I already tried many approaches including OH MY GOD: word[0]. I wouldn't be posting here if it was simply do a google search.

Comment: @kensai01 You don't think pointing out tag-spam is useful? The one (right) answer says what you claim to have done. Perhaps you need more detail in your question about the actual problem?

Comment: @John3136 can you help me understand why I would be getting a Segmentation fault when accessing it in such a fashion? That's the problem that prompted this post initially.

Comment: @kensai01 Almost certainly because the variable is unset (or set to 0 or garbage). Have you tried debugging (or just printing the value of `word`) to check?

Comment: `printf("line: %c\n", line[0]);`
    `printf(line[0]);`
First line prints fine, second line gets segmentation fault. I guess more precisely, how would I cast the second line[0] to be the correct type? (I think that's the correct question anyhow..)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147579/discussion-between-john3136-and-kensai01).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a tokenizer.

```
/*Tokenizer, splits the arguments and detects presence of i/o or piping.*/
void Tokenize(char *sentence, char** StorageArray, char * delimiter)
{
    char *token;
    char *next_token;
    int counter = 1, position = 0;
    token = strtok(sentence, delimiter);
    next_token = token;
    while (next_token != NULL){
        TokenCount++;
        StorageArray[position] = token;

        /*Check for input / output markers*/
        if(strcmp(StorageArray[position], "<") == 0){ flagInput = 1;}
        if(strcmp(StorageArray[position], ">") == 0){ flagOutput = 1;}
        /*Check for pipeline instructions.*/
        if(strcmp(StorageArray[position], "|") == 0){ flagPipeInst = 1;}

        position++;
        if((next_token = strtok(NULL, delimiter))){
            token = next_token;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    counter--;
}
```

I got all the tokens prior to passing things into the execute command.

Answer (score 0):

oh goodness, that archaic function parameter syntax!

To check the first element of a pointer array, simply use `ptr_name[0]` where "ptr_name" is the name/identifier of the pointer array.

if you're trying to see if a specific character is a hash/pound symbol. simply do:

```
if( word[0] == '#' ) // run code
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I already tried the word[0] way to access the element but this gives me a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I've also tried to iterate across the character array starting at the pointer and using pointer arithmetic but I still can't figure out how to access the first element. I must be missing something :(